# How do I do concurrent updates/lock and update records using C#

Tags: community, api, soap-api, query, c#

As I understand it, I cannot use `FOR UPDATE` keyword when selecting records via Salesforce SOAP API (wsdl) before I update them. How do I make concurrent updates on a record retrieved via API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to create your own REST or SOAP based API in Apex that would both lock and update the records required in one call. Then consume this API from C#.

**SOAP based:**

```
global class MyWebService {
    webService static Id makeContact(String lastNameParam, Account a) {

        Account lockedAccount = [Select Id from Account where Id = :a.Id FOR UPDATE];

        Contact c = new Contact(lastName = lastNameParam, AccountId = a.Id);
        insert c;
        return c.id;
    }
}
```

**REST based:**

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Contact/*')
global with sharing class ContactController {

    @HttpPost   
    global static Id makeContact(String lastNameParam, Id accountId) {

        Account lockedAccount = [Select Id from Account where Id = :accountId FOR UPDATE];

        Contact c = new Contact(lastName = lastNameParam, AccountId = accountId);
        insert c;
        return c.id;
    }
}
```

See [Exposing Apex Methods as SOAP Web Services](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_web_services.htm) and [Creating REST APIs using Apex REST](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_REST_APIs_using_Apex_REST)

Comment: It's kind of strange to mention both `SOAP` and `REST` but only provide an example for the former. Granted, OP only asks about `SOAP`.

Comment: Fair enough, I've expanded it with a REST based example as well.

Answer (score 2):

Row locks don't make sense in the nature of the SOAP/REST APIs, because the API isn't a continuous transaction like in other RDBM systems. For example, in MySQL, you'd open a socket, perform potentially a handful of back-and-forth operations, then commit your changes. In the Salesforce API, each call is literally its own transaction, so there's no opportunity to commit or rollback explicitly with the API.

If you're updating *different* fields on the exact same record, there's no need to use locking anyways, because the platform handles that for you automatically (rows are automatically implicitly locked for an entire API call). The best practice here is to not update an *entire* record, but only fields that a user changes, which saves bandwidth and reduces the odds of clobbering other updates.

If you need to enforce more complicated transactions, such as updating a parent record and several children records, with the option to rollback until the end, consider using the "webservice" keyword (SOAP) or the @HttpResource annotation (REST), and call some Apex Code using data you supply. This way, you're not left with a situation where your transactions are in a potentially irreversible invalid state. Alternatively, consider using triggers, workflows, process builder, etc to enforce cascading updates consistently.